# ValidationRules on controls inside UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, validationrules

EDIT: Found a solution that works for me here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/c1fd21b2-424b-4536-be8c-335cee94596a

As follows:

```
    private void TextBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Binding bd = new Binding(TextBoxText.ToString());
        bd.ValidationRules.Add(new DataErrorValidationRule());
        bd.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bd);
    }
```

and

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:wa="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<DockPanel
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Label
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type wa:UserControl1}},Path=LabelContent}"/>
    <TextBox
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        MinWidth="96"
        Loaded="TextBoxLoaded">
    </TextBox>
</DockPanel>
```

and

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wa="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="personDisplay">
        <DockPanel>
            <wa:UserControl1 LabelContent="First name:" TextBoxText="fname"/>
            <wa:UserControl1 LabelContent="Last name:" TextBoxText="lname"/>
            <wa:UserControl1 LabelContent="Age:" TextBoxText="age"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Name="personCcl"
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource personDisplay}"/>
```

END

I have a usercontrol that needs to contain a label and a textbox and the entry on the textbox needs to have a validationrule that checks the values entered are valid.  I have a datatemplate that displays a class that has multiple fields using the usercontrol.  The class implements the IDataErrorInfo.  However, the problem I have is that the textbox isn't accessing the classes IDataErrorInfo and additionally, the red outline that surrounds an invalid control, is around the entire usercontrol, not just the textbox inside the user control.

I've created a simpler example of what I'm trying to do below.

Here is the class

```
public class Person : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public Person(string f, string l, int a)
    {
        fname = f;
        lname = l;
        age = a;
    }
    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            if (age < 18) return "Too young";
            else if (fname == null || fname.Length == 0) return "Needs first name";
            else if (lname == null || lname.Length == 0) return "Needs last name";
            return null;
        }
    }
    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (name == "age") { return age < 18 ? "Too young" : null; }
            else if (name == "fname") { return fname == null || fname.Length == 0 ? "Needs first name" : null ; }
            else if (name == "lname") { return lname == null || lname.Length == 0 ? "Needs last name" : null; }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the usercontrol:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    static readonly public DependencyProperty LabelContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "LabelContent",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(UserControl1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("")
    );
    public string LabelContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(LabelContentProperty) as string; }
        set { SetValue(LabelContentProperty, value); }
    }
    static readonly public DependencyProperty TextBoxTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextBoxText",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(UserControl1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextBoxTextChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceTextBoxText))
    );
    public object TextBoxText
    {
        get { return GetValue(TextBoxTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBoxTextProperty, value); }
    }
    static private void OnTextBoxTextChanged(DependencyObject dob, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs ea)
    {
        var uc = dob as UserControl1;
        uc.OnTextBoxTextChanged(new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object>(ea.OldValue, ea.NewValue, TextBoxTextChangedEvent));
    }
    static private object CoerceTextBoxText(DependencyObject dob, object o)
    {
        return o;
    }
    static readonly public RoutedEvent TextBoxTextChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "TextBoxTextChanged",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object>),
        typeof(UserControl1));
    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object> TextBoxTextChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(TextBoxTextChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(TextBoxTextChangedEvent, value); }
    }
    protected virtual void OnTextBoxTextChanged(RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> ea) { RaiseEvent(ea); }
}
```

Here is usercontrol xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:wa="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<DockPanel>
    <Label
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
            AncestorType={x:Type wa:UserControl1}},
        Path=LabelContent}"/>
    <TextBox
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        MinWidth="96">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding 
                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType={x:Type wa:UserControl1}}"
                    Path="TextBoxText"
                    Mode="TwoWay"
                    UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Here is window xaml (updated):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wa="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="personDisplay">
        <DockPanel>
            <wa:UserControl1 LabelContent="First name:" TextBoxText="{Binding fname,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <wa:UserControl1 LabelContent="Last name:" TextBoxText="{Binding lname,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <wa:UserControl1 LabelContent="Age:" TextBoxText="{Binding age,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Name="personCcl"
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource personDisplay}"/>
</Window>
```

Here is Window constructor

```
    public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  personCcl.Content = new Person("John", "Smith", 33);
}
```

Comment: Corret me if I'm wrong. You want your validation for your TextBox and set it's DataContext to the ViewModel to fire the validation? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I'm still new to wpf so I can't articulate all the terms correctly.  For example, in the above code, on the textbox that holds the age value, if I type in 15, it should go to the person class and check the validation rule and determine, that's "Too young".  That doesn't happen though.  What appears to be happening, is that the binding of the textbox is just a string that gets validated.  I would like the validation to occur against the IDataErrorInfo on the person class but have it apply only to the particular textboxes not the entire user control.  Hope that helps explain things.

Comment: Have you set the DataContext of your ContentControl to be your Person's class?

Comment: Yes, sorry, in the Constructor for MainWindow, I edited the original post

Comment: Similar problem and solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997315/binding-nested-validation-rules-on-nested-user-controls/32839858#32839858

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong. Don't make personCc1.Content = new Person. Make it personCc1.DataContext = new Person. Content is expecting you to just display the values of that class and is mostly use for UI.

Comment: Ahh ok. I'll try it when I get a chance.  Thanks.